# Render callback on remoteIO audio unit does not receive audio samples

Tags: core-audio, audiounit

I've been trying to obtain samples that are played by kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO and that are received from kAudioUnitSubType_AudioFilePlayer.

To obtain these samples I configured a kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback on the output of the remoteIO Audio Unit (bus 0). While I am successful to play audio, this render callback does not seem to receive samples. To my understanding, the remoteIO callback pulls (renders) available data (stored on a buffer) from the FilePlayer Audio Unit (bus 1).

Does anyone know what goes wrong?

```
 NewAUGraph(player.graph)

 // Add file player node
 var cd = AudioComponentDescription(componentType: OSType(kAudioUnitType_Generator),
    componentSubType: OSType(kAudioUnitSubType_AudioFilePlayer),
    componentManufacturer: OSType(kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple),
    componentFlags: 0, componentFlagsMask: 0)
 AUGraphAddNode(player.graph, &cd, &player.filePlayerNode)

 // Add output node
 var rioNode = AUNode()
 cd.componentType = OSType(kAudioUnitType_Output)
 cd.componentSubType = OSType(kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO)
 AUGraphAddNode(player.graph, &cd, &rioNode)

 AUGraphOpen(player.graph)
 AUGraphNodeInfo(player.graph, player.filePlayerNode, nil, &player.filePlayerAU)
 AUGraphNodeInfo(player.graph, rioNode, nil, &player.rioAU)

 AUGraphConnectNodeInput(player.graph, player.filePlayerNode, 0, outputNode, 0)


 // The callback is configures as
 var callbackStruct = AURenderCallbackStruct(inputProc: InputRenderProc, inputProcRefCon: &player)
 CheckError(AudioUnitSetProperty(player.rioAU,
    kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback,
    kAudioUnitScope_Output,
    0,
    &callbackStruct,
    UInt32(sizeof(callbackStruct.dynamicType))),
    operation: "Couldn't set RIO's render callback")


 AUGraphInitialize(player.graph)
```

And the render callback (does not receive any data, neither gives any errors):

```
 let InputRenderProc: AURenderCallback = {(inRefCon, ioActionFlags, inTimeStamp, inBusNumber, inNumberFrames, ioData)  -> OSStatus in
    let player = UnsafeMutablePointer<StatePlayer>(inRefCon).memory

    // Just obtain samples from buffer
     var bus1: UInt32 = 1
    CheckError(AudioUnitRender(player.filePlayerAU, ioActionFlags, inTimeStamp, bus1, inNumberFrames, ioData),
        operation: "Couldn't render from filePlayer Audio Unit")

    return noErr
 }
```

Comment: Is the callback getting called?